# Change date in MM-DD-YY format in a formula within code to the next day

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code (as part of a bigger macro) to reference a cell in a specific dated file. The reference file is a daily backup version that is saved to a shared drive using mm-dd-yy format.

I want to use VBA code (using mm-dd-yy) to change this formula to reference the file for the next day, that is change "`05-07-14`" to "`05-08-14`":

```
Range("CL2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'G:\TCI_PM\Port Rept & Perf Track\Daily Reprojections\TPV datafiles\[TPV datafile - 05-07-14.xlsx]TPV Data Pull'!C1:C88,36,FALSE)"
```

Comment: This would be easier if you could convince your organisation to move away from number date and move to dd-mmm-yy so that it is always clear which is the month.  USA and UK have different conventions (as you know).  Using dd-mmm-yy could be an international standard in an organisation that has settled on one business language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to Parse a USA date that runs in UK...

```
Sub TestParseUSDate()
    Debug.Assert VBA.FormatDateTime(ParseUSDate("05-07-14"), vbLongDate) = "07 May 2014"
End Sub

Function ParseUSDate(ByVal sUSADate As String) As Date

    Debug.Assert Len(sUSADate) >= 8

    Dim lMonth As Long
    lMonth = Left$(sUSADate, 2)

    Debug.Assert Not (IsNumeric(Mid$(sUSADate, 3, 1)))

    Dim lDay As Long
    lDay = Mid$(sUSADate, 4, 2)

    Debug.Assert Not (IsNumeric(Mid$(sUSADate, 6, 1)))

    Dim lYear As Long
    lYear = Mid$(sUSADate, 7)

    Dim dt As Date
    ParseUSDate = VBA.DateTime.DateSerial(lYear, lMonth, lDay)


End Function
```

Comment: I need the day reference to keep moving forward by a day. I revised my code as-

Answer (score 0):

I have most of it working except....I am not sure how to combine the path and file reference to have the formula set up right.

The formula should look like "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'U:\00_Daily Reports["TPV datafile_2 - " & "myname" & ".xlsx"]TPV Data Pull'!C1:C88,36,FALSE)"

The code that I have now is:

```
Dim path As String
Dim file As String
Dim myformula As String
Dim myname As Date

myname = Day(Now() - 1)
path = "U:\00_Daily Reports\"
file = "TPV datafile_2 - " & "myname" & ".xlsx""

myformula = "-------------------------"
Range("CL2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = myformula
```